# Задача с ассоциативным массивом

Tags: php, массивы

В массиве есть авторы и книги, у каждой книги один автор.

```
$authors = [
   'Гоголь' => ['Николай Васильевич', 'gogol@gogol.ru', '1809'],
   'Пушкин' => ['Александр Сергеевич', 'alexandr@sergeevich.ru', '1799'],
   'Салтыков - Щедрин' => ['Михаил Евграфович', 'shedrin@yandex.ru', '1826'],
   'Мертвые души' => ['Николай Васильевич', '1842'],
   'Вечера на хуторе близ Диканьки' => ['Николай Васильевич','1831'],
   'История одного города' => ['Михаил Евграфович', '1891'],
   'Пиковая дама' => ['Сергей Александрович', '1834'],
   'Капитанская дочка' => ['Сергей Александрович', '1836'],
];
```

Вопрос:
Как вывести информацию по всем авторам?(Имя автора - email - год рождения)
Как не указывать повторно имя автора в значении для каждой из книг?

Comment: Покажите, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Не очень понятно из вашего вопроса

Comment: `$authors['Гоголь'][0] .  '-' . $authors['Гоголь'][1] .  '-' .$authors['Гоголь'][2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
array_walk($authors,function($v){ echo implode(' - ',$v).'<br>'; });
```