# Вывод элементов из многомерных массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Всем приветик. Возник следующий вопрос:

```
$result3 = [ 
    // массив с авторами 
    'authors' => [
        'Email 1' => ['Name 1', '1994'], 
        'Email 2' => ['Name 2', '1996'],
        'Email 3' => ['Name 3', '1998'], 
        'Email 4' => ['Name 4', '1990'],
        'Email 5' => ['Name 5', '1985'],
    ],

    //добавление элемента в массив
    'books' => [
        'book1' => ['Book name 1', 'Author email 1'], 
        'book2' => ['Book name 2', 'Author email 2'],
        'book3' => ['Book name 3', 'Author email 3'], 
        'book4' => ['Book name 4', 'Author email 4'],
        'book5' => ['Book name 5', 'Author email 5'],
    ],
];
```

Нужно вывести эти массивы следующим образом:

Книга (Book name), ее написал (Name) (1994) (Author email)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/876379/223826 - ваш коллега что ли?

Comment: начните с простого цикла по книгам и вывода их  названия. потом добавьте свой код, и напишите в чем у вас возникает сложность

Comment: на таких примерах, который ниже, можно понять как работает код, это полезно. Чем больше таких примеров тем лучше)

Comment: Это уже третий вопрос про книги, какие-то курсы походу проходят.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($result3['books'] as $book){
    echo "Книга ".$book[0].
         ", ее написал ".$result3['authors'][$book[1]][0].
         " в ".$result3['authors'][$book[1]][1].
         "его email ".$book[1];
}
```